# pentaho data integration output excel file not retrieving all query results

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

In the ETL I have a excel table input which executes SQL code, which goes into an excel table output.

Th SQL code has 5 select statements, but in the excel table output only the results of the first select statement are showing. How can I get all of the results to show in the output.

Comment: Are all the SQL statements are combined using UNION/ UNION ALL?

Comment: no they are not as the queries are for different tables, good idea though may try a union on them, any other ideas?

Comment: Usually, we use only one query in a table input. That one query might have UNION/ UNION ALL. If all the queries can not be used in UNION then you can have separate transformations and use the excel output with the append options without the header.